# C8051F340 USB device data transfer silicon lab IDE

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I am trying to write a device code for C8051F340 to get the data from the host(PC) via USB. I have some example from silicon lab and the code look like below:

```
void  Receive_File(void)
{
   ReadStageLength = ((BytesToRead - BytesRead) > MAX_BLOCK_SIZE_READ)? MAX_BLOCK_SIZE_READ:(BytesToRead - BytesRead);

   BytesRead   += Block_Read((U8*)(&TempStorage[BlockIndex]), ReadStageLength);   // Read Block

   BlockIndex++;
  // If device has received as many bytes as fit on one FLASH page, disable interrupts,
  // write page to flash, reset packet index, enable interrupts
  // Send handshake packet 0xFF to host after FLASH write
   if ((BlockIndex   == (BLOCKS_PR_PAGE)) || (BytesRead  == BytesToRead))
 {
  Page_Erase((U8*)(PageIndices[PageIndex]));
  Page_Write((U8*)(PageIndices[PageIndex]));
  PageIndex++;
  Led1 = !Led1;
  BlockIndex  =  0;
  Buffer[0]   =  0xFF;
  Block_Write(Buffer,  1);         // Send handshake Acknowledge to host
 }

// Go to Idle state if last packet has been received
if (BytesRead  == BytesToRead)   {M_State =  ST_IDLE_DEV;   Led1  =  0;}
}

// Startup code for SDCC to disablt WDT before initializing variables so  that
// a reset does not occur
 #if defined SDCC
void _sdcc_external_startup (void)
{
 PCA0MD &= ~0x40;                    // Disable Watchdog timer
}
#endif
```

I have some questions want to ask:
1. Where the data goes? the Buffer [0]? 
2. if I got a Hex value transfer from the host, can I just read the Buffer [0] to get it ?
sorry I am a newbie.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your received data stored in array `TempStorage`
You used Buufer[0] (the value 0xFF)   for to send data to host